# Role not assigned to user

Tags: federated-authentication

I am trying to implement `federated login` for my website in `Sitecore 9.1`. We are using Open Id connect with an implicit flow so that we upon authentication receive an `identity-token`.

I've written a config file and overridden the IdentityProcessor, and it seems that everything is working. When I hit the login link I get redirected to the external login page and when I am authenticated there I get redirected back to my website. However, when I check to see if I have the roles that I have specified in the transformation-node in my config file, they're not assigned to my user?

**The token I'm receiving is:**

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256"}{"sub":"anonymousUser","aud":"03ffdc3a-9328-4912-8c73-a40ddb09cd85","nbf":1563539052,"role":"write","idp":"demo","iss":"https:\/\/xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xx","name":"anonymousUser","company":"[\"companyA\",\"companyB\"]","exp":1563539412,"iat":1563539111,"nonce":"636991359115494880.ODU1ZDQ2ZDEtNTI0Ni00YmJmLThhMmQtYTc5MjFiZjY1YTY5N2M0ODBjZGQtMjdkMS00NGU2LWIwNDktYWNkYzFmYWNiZmYz","jti":"0b9e6dca-29c1-4a3b-8ea3-95a1f23b5d43"}
```

**and my config is:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
      <services>
          <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                    implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                    lifetime="Singleton" />
          <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                    implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                    lifetime="Singleton" />
          <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                    implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                    lifetime="Singleton" />
      </services>
      <pipelines>
          <owin.identityProviders>
              <processor type="SC.Foundation.Login.Infrastructure.Pipelines.XxIdentityProvider, SC.Foundation.Login" resolve="true"/>
          </owin.identityProviders>
      </pipelines>
      <federatedAuthentication>
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
              <identityProvider id="demo" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                  <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                  <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                  <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                      <transformation name="set idp claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />
                      <transformation name="readRole" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                          <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                              <claim name="role" value="read" />
                          </sources>
                          <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                              <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="extranet\read" />
                          </targets>
                          <keepSource>true</keepSource>
                      </transformation>
                      <transformation name="writeRole" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                          <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                              <claim name="role" value="write" />
                          </sources>
                          <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                              <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="extranet\write" />
                          </targets>
                          <keepSource>true</keepSource>
                      </transformation>
                  </transformations>
              </identityProvider>
          </identityProviders>
          <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
              <!--The list of providers assigned to all sites-->
              <mapEntry name="xUsers" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                  <sites hint="list">
                      <site>website</site>
                  </sites>
                  <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                      <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='demo']" />
                  </identityProviders>
                  <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                      <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
                  </externalUserBuilder>
              </mapEntry>

          </identityProvidersPerSites>
          <sharedTransformations hint="list:AddSharedClaimsTransformation">
              <!--Adds idp claim to identity. Every provider should reference to it-->
              <setIdpClaim name="setIdpClaim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"/>
              <nameClaimTransformation name="nameClaimTransformation" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                  <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                      <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier"/>
                  </sources>
                  <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                      <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"/>
                  </targets>
                  <keepSource>true</keepSource>
              </nameClaimTransformation>


          </sharedTransformations>
      </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

So specifically I want my user to receive the extranet/write role that I created

[image]

**My processor looks like:**

```
        using Sitecore.Abstractions;
        using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.IdentityProviders;
        using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration;
        using SC.Foundation.Login.Models;
        using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
        using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
        using Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure;
        using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
        using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
        using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
        using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;

        namespace SC.Foundation.Login.Infrastructure.Pipelines
        {
            using Owin;

            public class XxIdentityProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
            {
                private ClientData clientData;

                private DecryptionKey decryptionKey;

                protected override string IdentityProviderName => "demo";

                public XxIdentityProvider(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, ICookieManager cookieManager, BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
                {
                    decryptionKey = new DecryptionKey
                    {
                        FilePath = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("DecryptionKeyPath"),
                        Password = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("DecryptionKeyPassword")
                    };

                    clientData = new ClientData
                    {
                        ClientId = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ClientId"),
                        AuthorizationEndpoint = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("AuthorizationEndpoint"),
                        ValidIssuer = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ValidIssuer"),
                        SigningKeyPath = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("SigningKeyPath"),
                        DecryptionKey = decryptionKey
                    };
                }

                protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
                {
                    var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();

                    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

                    args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
                    });

                    var tokenValidationParameters = (new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        TokenDecryptionKey = clientData.DecryptingCertificate(),
                        IssuerSigningKey = clientData.SigningCertificate(),
                        ValidIssuer = clientData.ValidIssuer,
                        ValidAudience = clientData.ClientId
                    });

                    var openIdConnectConfiguration = (new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                    {
                        AuthorizationEndpoint = clientData.AuthorizationEndpoint
                    });

                    args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        ClientId = clientData.ClientId,
                        AuthenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType(),
                        Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                        {
                            AuthorizationEndpoint = clientData.AuthorizationEndpoint
                        },
                        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,
                        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                        {
                           SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                           {


                               notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
                               return Task.CompletedTask;
                           },

                       },
                       RedirectUri = "http://virk.xm1.dk/",
                       ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                       TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

When I try to see if my user has the role extranet/write after login

```
Role role = Role.FromName(@"extranet\write");
var isInRole = Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole(role);
```

I get false.

However, I can see that a user is created in my `User manager`
[image]
but when I try to write out the users username

```
var username = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Current.Name;
```

I don't get the gibberish string `dSEvLyc6hQ` but just `extranet\Anonymous`.

This is the first time I'm trying to implement federated login in Sitecore, so maybe I'm missing something basic or have misunderstood something? Can I only assign the roles through a custom Transformation instead of `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation`? Or are these roles only available in CM and not CD?

Furthermore, another problem I'm encountering is that I can't use my own custom domain for my users. If I use the following `eai` domain that I've created in Sitecore
[image]
in my config file

```
<domain>eai</domain>
```

I get the following error page when trying to hit my website
[image]

Is this not possible or what am I doing wrong?

Hope you all can bear with me.

Comment: can you please make sure that you have added domain node under identityProvider section in the Owin configuration - <domain>eai</domain>

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat It is added. I didn't include in the example above because the first question pertains to the transformations. I added a code segment to my original post to clarify that the domain node with eai is added when i get the yellow error page

Comment: Hey @suma1729 - was this ever resolved?